# $g=h_1...h_n$ and $h_i h_j=h_jh_i$

Tags: group-theory

> I want to prove that if we have sets $H_i\subset G$, where $G$ is group and these two conditions hold:
>
> 1. $g\in G\Rightarrow \exists ! h_i \in H_i \: \text{such that} \: g=h_1....h_n$
> 2. $h_ih_j=h_jh_i$ if $h_i\in H_i$ and $h_j \in H_j$ for every $i\not=j$
>
> Then  $H_i\leq G$

I tried taking $h_i , \hat{h}_i$ in $H_i$. From the first condition we have:

$$h_i \hat{h}_i^{-1}=h_1...\bar{h}_i...h_n$$

We need to show that $h_1=...=h_{i-1}=h_{i+1}=...=h_n=1$. From the second condition, when we multiply this last equation by $\hat{h}_i$, we have:

$$h_i=h_1...(\bar{h}_i\hat{h}_i)...h_n$$

I wanted to use unicity from the first condition, but it could be that $\bar{h}_i\hat{h}_i\not \in H_i$. How do I show $H_i\leq G$? Is this even true?

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not true. Consider $G = \mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z} = \{0,1,2,3\}$, $H_1 = \{0,2\}$, $H_2 = \{0,1\}$.